# python-binance i can create a reduceonly order

Tags: python, automation, trading, binance

i have 1 binance account with humen activity (with hedge mood)
and 1 more biance account listening to the humen account and try copy all order is make.

when a humen create a order, the bot account make it to.

but, when humen create a reduceOnly order and bot try to copy it, the bot get an error like this
APIError(code=-1106) Parameter 'reduceOnly' sent when not required.

the code is like this:

```
result = self.client.futures_create_order(
symbol=symbol,
side  =side,
positionSide=positionSide,
type  =Ttype,
timeInForce=timeInForce,
reduceOnly=True,
quantity=float(quantity), # with max 3 number after the point
price=price
```

)

something is worng, how is possible the humen can create a "reduceOnly order" and the bot c'anot?

Answer (score -1):

you are using so many unnecessary parameters. this should work:

```
client.futures_create_order(
symbol = 'BNBUSDT'
,side='SELL'
, closePosition=True
, stopPrice=415
,type='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET')
```